# Arrows in the definition of dual of category

Tags: haskell, category-theory

> Given any category `CatC`, you can construct another category denoted `CatC`<sup>op</sup> by reversing all the arrows. The dual or opposite `CatC`<sup>op</sup> of a category `CatC` is defined by:
>
> D-1 The objects and arrows of `CatC`<sup>op</sup> are the objects and arrows of `CatC`
>
> D-2 If `f: A -> B` in `CatC`, then `f: B -> A` in `CatC`<sup>op</sup>.
>
> D-3 If `h = g . f` in `CatC`, then `h = f . g` in `CatC`<sup>op</sup>.

My question is the conflict of `D-2` and `D-1`, each arrow in `CatC`<sup>op</sup> is the reverse of the corresponding on in `CatC`. Why `D-1` says that the arrows of `CatC`<sup>op</sup> are the arrows of `CatC`?

Comment: This might need to be moved to MathExchange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd consider this a bit off-topic for Stack Overflow, but I'll just answer anyway.

The morphisms and objects themselves don't change.  They are the same.  What we get to re-define are the domain and the codomain that we consider each morphism to have.  So if *x* is a morphism in in ***C***, ***C*** gets to define *dom(x)* and *cod(x)*.

Let's say I have a morphism in ***C*** and ***C***<sup>op</sup>, I'll call it *x*.  In ***C***, it's defined that *dom(x) = X*, and *cod(f) = Y*.  Cool.  Now, when we define our new category ***C***<sup>op</sup>, we get to define *dom(x)* and *cod(f)* however we like.  We'll define *dom(x)* (remember, we can call it whatever we want) as *Y*, and *cod(x)* as *X*.  That's the "rule" of constructing a dual category.

Remember that morphisms aren't functions, in general...they're just structureless things.  In a given Category we can imbue them with domains and codomains, but they're just sort of like meaningless/structureless tags.

You can think of morphisms as a bag of things, each with two properties given by the category: a domain and a codomain.  The category itself can specify the domain and the codomain however they like; they're just like arbitrary "tags".

For example, the category ***L*** whose objects are the natural numbers and where a single morphism exists between any two numbers numbers, where the domain is defined as the number that is higher and the codomain is defined as the number that is lower.  There's also a single morphism from each number to itself.  So there is a morphism *x* whose domain is 5 and whose codomain is 2.  And there is another morphism *y* whose domain is 10 and whose codomain is 3 (only one such morphism exists, here).  There is no morphism whose domain is 5 and codomain is 11.  It's not a part of our bag of morphisms.  There *is* a morphism between 5 and 11, but its domain is 11 and its codomain is 5.

Well, we can now define a new category, ***L***<sup>op</sup>, whose objects are the natural numbers and which has all of the morphisms from ***L***.  *x* is still there, and *y* is still there...*x* and *y* are just things in a bag.  Only, now, we look at *x*, and we say that its domain is 2 and its codomain is 5, and we look at *y* and say that its domain is 3 and its codomain is 10.  We just "tag" it with different numbers.  And what numbers do we tag *x*, *y* with?  Exactly the numbers they were tagged with in ***L***, except flipped.

In ***L***<sup>op</sup>, is there a morphism whose domain is 5 and whose codomain is 1?  Well, to find one, we would need to find a morphism whose domain in ***L*** was tagged as 1 and whose codomain in ***L*** was tagged as 5.  But no such morphism exists.  So no, no such morphism exists in ***L***<sup>op</sup>

So, in both cases, the morphism in question is exactly the same.  But the difference is what we "call" the domain and what we "call" the codomain.